# Django Deployment With Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my existing django project with heroku, following the walk through provided by heroku and adapting as needed to be specific to my project. Just to run quickly through what I've done so far:

- installed django-toolbelt in my virtualenv
- created a Procfile in the root of my project named `Procile` which includes:

  ```
  web: gunicorn projectname.wsgi
  ```
- using `foreman start` confirmed that my project still ran properly locally
- created `requirements.txt` using `pip freeze` and placed it in the root of my project
- added the following to `settings.py`:

  ```
  import dj_database_url
  DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()

  # Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
  SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

  # Allow all host headers
  ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

  # Static asset configuration
  import os
  BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
  STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
  STATIC_URL = '/static/'

   STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
  )
  ```

This is one point where I'm a bit confused, the walkthrough made no mention of what happens with my existing db settings, leave as is, remove, change?

- Added the following to wsgi.py:

  ```
  from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
  from dj_static import Cling

  application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
  ```
- added heroku as a git remote and pushed my project to heroku. It worked.
- `heroku ps:scale web=1`

However, when I try to access my project I get an `Application Error`. When I check the status with heroku `heroku ps --app projectname` it says the dyno has crashed. Restarting does nothing.

`heroku logs --app projectname` yields:

```
2013-07-18T00:01:14.246956+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn projectname.wsgi`
2013-07-18T00:01:16.054952+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-07-18 00:01:16 [2] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 17.5
2013-07-18T00:01:16.058972+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-07-18 00:01:16 [2] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:55131 (2)
2013-07-18T00:01:16.061566+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-07-18 00:01:16 [2] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2013-07-18T00:01:16.080073+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-07-18 00:01:16 [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2013-07-18T00:01:16.091347+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2013-07-18T00:01:16.091347+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 473, in spawn_worker
2013-07-18T00:01:16.091347+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_process
2013-07-18T00:01:16.091347+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2013-07-18T00:01:16.091347+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2013-07-18T00:01:16.091347+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2013-07-18T00:01:16.091558+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 353, in import_app
2013-07-18T00:01:16.091347+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2013-07-18T00:01:16.091558+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2013-07-18T00:01:16.091347+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-07-18 00:01:16 [7] [ERROR] Exception in  worker process:
2013-07-18T00:01:16.091347+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 33, in load
2013-07-18T00:01:16.091558+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2013-07-18T00:01:16.091771+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2013-07-18T00:01:16.091771+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2013-07-18T00:01:16.091558+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_process
2013-07-18T00:01:16.091558+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 115, in wsgi
2013-07-18T00:01:16.091771+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 33, in load
2013-07-18T00:01:16.091347+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 115, in wsgi
2013-07-18T00:01:16.091558+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 473, in spawn_worker
2013-07-18T00:01:16.091558+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2013-07-18T00:01:16.091771+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named projectname.wsgi
2013-07-18T00:01:16.091558+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named projectname.wsgi
2013-07-18T00:01:16.091558+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2013-07-18T00:01:16.091558+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2013-07-18T00:01:16.099257+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-07-18 00:01:16 [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2013-07-18T00:01:16.091771+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 353, in import_app
2013-07-18T00:01:16.286985+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-07-18 00:01:16 [2] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2013-07-18T00:01:16.288144+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-07-18 00:01:16 [2] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2013-07-18T00:01:17.956769+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2013-07-18T00:01:17.981029+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-07-18T00:11:46.404151+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-07-18T00:11:50.427658+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn projectname.wsgi`
2013-07-18T00:11:51.405718+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-07-18 00:11:51 [2] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 17.5
2013-07-18T00:11:51.406995+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-07-18 00:11:51 [2] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:21344 (2)
2013-07-18T00:11:51.407226+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-07-18 00:11:51 [2] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2013-07-18T00:11:51.418300+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-07-18 00:11:51 [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425145+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425145+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 33, in load
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425145+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-07-18 00:11:51 [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425145+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425145+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425145+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425145+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 115, in wsgi
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425145+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425145+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 473, in spawn_worker
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425145+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_process
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425341+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 353, in import_app
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425341+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425341+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named projectname.wsgi
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425341+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425341+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 473, in spawn_worker
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425341+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_process
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425341+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425341+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425341+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 115, in wsgi
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425341+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425513+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425513+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 33, in load
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425513+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 353, in import_app
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425513+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425513+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named projectname.wsgi
2013-07-18T00:11:51.425868+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-07-18 00:11:51 [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2013-07-18T00:11:51.550395+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-07-18 00:11:51 [2] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2013-07-18T00:11:51.550395+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-07-18 00:11:51 [2] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2013-07-18T00:11:52.851413+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2013-07-18T00:11:52.867339+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-07-18T00:14:14.285978+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=projectname.herokuapp.com fwd="173.54.54.86" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-18T00:14:14.405875+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=projectname.herokuapp.com fwd="173.54.54.86" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated, I found no way to contact heroku directly on this, everything refers you here to so.

Answer (score 3):

> This is one point where I'm a bit confused, the walkthrough made no
>   mention of what happens with my existing db settings, leave as is,
>   remove, change?

I too followed their walkthrough and had the same problems. For me it was the DATABASES statement that made the error. I replaced my database configuration with the one they provide, while it must just be added to the dictionary already created by your database settings. So instead of replacing your database statement just add:

```
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a possibility that Heroku has identified the wrong type of application during the build process.  This happened to me:

```
(venv)josephs-mbp:myproject josephfusaro$ git push heroku master
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 27, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Writing objects: 100% (14/14), 1.26 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 14 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Node.js app detected
```

This jumped out at me, because I am building a Python/Django app.  I came across [this Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171169/why-is-my-flask-app-being-detected-as-node-js-on-heroku) which explains how it can happen and shows how you can override the build pack. For this example, we'll be specifying the Python buildpack but you can instruct Heroku to use the buildpack for whatever type of application you're building ([click here for a full list](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#default-buildpacks))

```
heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python
```

Answer (score 0):

Well not really sure . Although the documentation of heroku recommends the way you have tried . I am really not sure where gunicorn get installed in heroku and how it is importing the django project . The more likely way to the process/server with django settings seems to be

web: bin/gunicorn_django --workers=4 --bind=0.0.0.0:$PORT django_project/settings.py

as recommended here :
http://blog.abhiomkar.in/2011/09/17/deploying-django-on-heroku-mac-os-x/

Comment: Thanks, however that doesn't detail what happens with my database settings.

Comment: Well you can use something like this ATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://settings_stuff')} . Also you should check  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connection-in-python to understand connecting to db

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': dj_database_url.config(default='sqlite:///db.sqlite')
}
```

this form can used locally and on heroku