# Why is my Flask app being detected as node.js on Heroku

Tags: python, node.js, heroku, flask

I recently made some changes to the structure of my Flask app hosted on heroku and now heroku has decided to detect it as a Node.js app intead of a Python app. My application uses both python (Flask) for the backend api and javascript for the front end.

The changes I made included integrating npm and bower into my application to streamline the javascript development of the app.

Comment: I ended up googling for answers and was able to find a vaguely similar post on StackOverflow which led me to figure out the answer. I just posted this to give a faster solution for people who had the same issue as me.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem was introduced when I added a `package.json` to my root directory when I started using npm. It seems that the build detection script runs the nodejs detection first ([here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/master/bin/detect)) which leads to this code: `if [ -f $1/package.json ]; then
  echo "Node.js" && exit 0` executing and Heroku thinks it's a nodejs app and exits before the python detection has a chance to run.

To solve this I had to manually tell Heroku that I wanted a python build using this command

`heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python`.

Comment: Side note: I had a problem running the `heroku config:set` command (on OS X) initially because I had an outdated heroku toolbelt which was very easily remedied by updating it at toolbelt.heroku.com

Comment: This worked; note that I had to push another commit to trigger the change however. heroku restart wasn't enough

Answer (score 23):

The `package.json` file is causing Heroku to detect it as a node.js app.  To prevent this, add the file name to a [`.slugignore`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#ignoring-files-with-slugignore) file:

```
echo 'package.json' >> .slugignore
git add .slugignore
```

---

`.slugignore` is like `.gitignore`. It resides in the root directory of your repository and should contain a list of filenames and wildcard patterns.  The matching files remain in your git repository, but are deleted from the slug after you push to Heroku.  The deletion occurs before the buildpacks run, so the node.js buildpack won't find `package.json` and the app won't be misidentified as a node.js app.

Comment: This solution is much more elegant.