# Can't deploy initial Flask app to Heroku "no Cedar-supported app detected", works with Foreman

Tags: python-2.7, heroku, flask, gunicorn

I'm having trouble deploying a Flask app to Heroku. I've successfully created the app on Heroku, it runs fine locally with Foreman, I've got my Procfile right (I think) and my requirements.txt in the root of the directory. I still have to set up environment variables and a connection to AWS RDS Postgres database I'm using, but I'm not even there yet. My inital push to Heroku keeps failing.

This is my error with I try to `git push herok master`:

```
Counting objects: 219, done.  
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.  
Compressing objects: 100% (206/206), done.  
Writing objects: 100% (219/219), 274.75 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.  
Total 219 (delta 98), reused 0 (delta 0)  
remote: Compressing source files... done.  
remote: Building source:  
remote:  
remote:  
remote:  !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected  
remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack  
remote:       to use for this application automatically.  
remote: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks  
remote:  
remote: Verifying deploy... 

remote:  
remote: !   Push rejected to my-awesome-app.  
remote:  
To https://git.heroku.com/my-awesome-app.git`
```

Here's my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn app:app --log-file=-
```

Here's my filestructure:

```
\project  (git root directory)
   Procfile
   requirements.txt
   [...other files...] 
    run.py
    \venv
    \etl  
    \app
     [...other files...]  
      \static  
      \templates
```

I've looked around a lot and haven't found anything to help.

Happy to add any additional information if that'd be helpful. This is very discouraging!

Comment: Your Procfile needs to be in the root of your Git repo.

Comment: Do you have a `package.json` for managing JavaScript resources by any chance? This can cause Heroku to mistakenly see the project as a node.js one instead of Python as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171169/why-is-my-flask-app-being-detected-as-node-js-on-heroku).

Comment: @elithrar thank you, the issue is happening with the Procfile in the root folder, I've added that as a note in the file structure above.

Comment: @jonafato thanks for responding, I don't have a package.json file unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, this was my mistake. I had *.txt in my .gitignore, and didn't realize I wasn't adding/committing requirements.txt to the git repo. Which...explains why heroku couldn't find it!

Answer (score 1):

In your repository's root directory, type:

```
echo "python-2.7.10" > runtime.txt
```

*If you are using a different version of Python, see [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes) for the supported runtimes.*

Add `runtime.txt` to your git repository and do a push to heroku. It should force it to detect your application as a Python app.

Comment: This was very helpful, I didn't know I had to be using a different python runtime, and I did have 2.7.9 installed. I upgraded my virtualenv to 2.7.10 and added the runtime.txt file, but to no avail, still having the problem.